# NetSuite Suitelet: How to display created custom body field in sublist?

Tags: netsuite

I created a saved search in suitelet with a custom field(custbody) or column.
sample code:
var dnote = result.getText('custbody_kd_so_notes'); // this will display blank in the sublist

but for code:
var dnote = result.getValue('custbody_kd_so_notes'); // it will give me an error

Can anybody give me a possible code to pull the values from the custom field? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get the value from the sublist itself, try using `sublist.getSublistValue()` as described in the help docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_452837158202.html).

If you're trying to get it from the search, let me know what error you're seeing. It sounds like it might be a simple bug somewhere possibly.

I also wrote a series on Suitelets [here](https://suiterep.com/2021/02/18/build-a-suitelet-with-the-ui-serverwidget-module-part-1/) incase you're interested.